# Composition rather than inheritance for shared variables

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, composition

I was previously using a class that could be simplfied down to this:

```
class Whatever {

  var someArray = [Int]()

  func unchangingFunction {
    print("test")
  }

  func functionForOverride() {}

}
```

I was asking of ways to improve this, and I got told to favour composition over inheritance, using something like the following:

```
protocol Implementation {
  func functionForOverride()
}

final class Whatever {

  var someArray = [Int]() // How can I access this?

  let implementation: Implementation

  init(implementation: Implementation) {
    self.implementation = implementation
  }

  func unchangingFunction() {
    print("test")
  }

  func functionForOverride() {
    implementation.functionForOverride()
  }

}
```

However, with this, I can't find a way to do anything with the someArray array:

```
struct Something: Implementation {

  func functionForOverride() {
    print(someArray) // This cannot work
  }

}
```

With the original code I am able to access and alter someArray however I want, but with this new way, I can't think of an easy solution.

Comment: What are *actually* trying to achieve?  `Something` is completely unrelated to `Implementation` so why would you expect it to be able to access `someArray`. I think you want `someArray` to be part of the `Implementation` protocol

Comment: I'm trying to use Something as a base for all levels in a game, and all the levels need to access someArray at some point

Comment: You need to decide if `someArray` should be part of the protocol, in which case each class or struct instance that implements your protocol will have its own `someArray` or whether `someArray` is something that needs to be passed to the function

Comment: It needs to be passed

Comment: Ok, so there's your answer. Your protocol needs to declare `func functionForOverride(someArray:[Int])`

Comment: I would agree with Paulw11, use a return value and a parameter, and your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 'Implementation' requires 'someArray' to do what it is intended to do, then you should have 'Implementation' require any object conforming to it to also declare 'someArray'

Like this:

```
protocol Implementation {
    var someArray: [Int]
}
```

And if you know what you want to do with 'someFunction', then you could give a default implementation of it with a protocol extension like so:

```
extension Implementation {
    func someFunction() {
        //you can do some stuff with someArray here
    }
}
```

Then when you conform to 'Implementation' you need to declare 'someArray' but not 'someFunction', unless you want to override the default function.

E.g.

```
class MyClass: Implementation {
     var someArray: [Int]!

     init() {}
}
```

Note that MyClass now has access to 'someFunction', which can be freely overridden in your class, and that you can add as many functions as you want to 'Implementation's extension.

Comment: Why not just passing the array as an argument as @Paulw11 proposed?

Answer (score 2):

I think we should use a "real" example in order to make things clearer.

### Inheritance (and why it's wrong)

We have the following classes

```
class Robot {
    var battery = 0

    func charge() {
        print("⚡️")
        battery += 1
    }
}

class Human {
    func eat() {
        print("")
    }
}

class RobotCleaner: Robot {
    func clean() {
        print("")
    }
}

class HumanCleaner: Human {
    func clean() {
        print("")
    }
}
```

**Code duplication!!!**

As you can see the `clean()` method is duplicated in `RobotCleaner` and `HumanCleaner`. Can you find a way (using inheritance) to remove code duplication?

Ok think about that, I'll wait on the next paragraph... :)

...

Oh, here you are! There's no way to fix that with inheritance right? Well, let's see what we can do with **composition**.

### Composition (the classic way)

Let's define the following 3 protocols and related components

```
protocol Robot {
    mutating func charge()
}
struct RobotComponent: Robot {
    var battery = 0
    mutating func charge() {
        print("⚡️")
        battery += 1
    }
}

protocol Human {
    func eat()
}
struct HumanComponent: Human {
    func eat() {
        print("")
    }
}

protocol Cleaner {
    func clean()
}
struct CleanerComponent: Cleaner {
    func clean() {
        print("")
    }
}
```

Now we can build any combination of the previous 3 elements

```
struct RobotCleaner: Robot, Cleaner {
    var robotComponent = RobotComponent()
    let cleanerComponent = CleanerComponent()

    mutating func charge() {
        robotComponent.charge()
    }

    func clean() {
        cleanerComponent.clean()
    }

}

struct HumanCleaner: Human, Cleaner {
    let humanComponent = HumanComponent()
    let cleanerComponent = CleanerComponent()

    func eat() {
        humanComponent.eat()
    }

    func clean() {
        cleanerComponent.clean()
    }   
}
```

### Protocol Oriented Programming: Composition the Swifty way

Swift offers a very neat way of doing composition.

First of all let's define the following 3 protocols (and related extensions).

```
protocol Robot {
    var battery: Int { get set }
}
extension Robot {
    mutating func charge() {
        print("⚡️")
        battery += 1
    }
}

protocol Human { }
extension Human {
    func eat() {
        print("")
    }
}

protocol Cleaner { }
extension Cleaner {
    func clean() {
        print("")
    }
}
```

Now we can create a Type which has any combination of the previous 3 entities. Let's see how.

```
struct HumanCleaner: Human, Cleaner { }
struct RobotCleaner: Robot, Cleaner {
    var battery: Int = 0
}
```

Comment: Yes I know it's like what Apple told at WWDC, but it's not really protocol oriented coding. Think about that: "struct HumanRobot: Human, Robot {}" That shouldn't be possible to construct, or? Take your first code snipped. Rename eat to charge and move it into a protocol Consumer. Define human and robot as Consumer, define a protocol Cleaner with a function clean() and write a class RoomCleaner that decorate a Consumer and implement the additional protocol Cleaner. Create objects like that: "let robotCleaner = RoomCleaner(Robot())" & "let humanCleaner = RoomCleaner(Human())" - Voila.

Comment: And now the best: You can write more decorator for Consumer and Cleaner without changing the implementations. For instance: You can write a Consumer decorator that get two Consumer and split the task charge to both. "let humanCleanerGroup = RoomCleaner(ConsumerGroup(Human(), Human))" That real protocol oriented programming, not that strange swifty apple stuff ;)